# center of the frobenius group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be a prime number. We define the frobenius group by

$F_{p(p-1}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&1\end{pmatrix}, a\in \mathbb{F}_p^{\times}, b\in \mathbb{F}_p\right\}$

I want to identify the center $Z(F_{p(p-1)})$ and $F'_{p(p-1)}=[F_{p(p-1)}:F_{p(p-1)}]$

with I will be gratefull if you could help me.

Comment: Have you tried working out a few small cases to see what they might look like?

Comment: I convinced myself that the center must be the identity matrix and nothing else. 
 but i don't manage to prove that. please help me. Thanks

Comment: The proof is essentially identical to the proof that the center of the group of all the matrices is trivial.

Comment: how can i do that, I didn't manage to answer

Comment: Just pick a non-identity element and define an element that does not commute with it based on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: let $g_1=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&1\end{pmatrix}, a\in \mathbb{F}_p^{\times}, b\in \mathbb{F}_p$ such that $a\neq 1$ and $b\neq0$ there exsit $g_2=\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ such that $g_1\neq g_2$ right?

Answer (score 0):

The centre of a group is defined as
$$Z(F_{p(p-1)})=\{A\in F_{p(p-1)}|\forall B\in F_{p(p-1)}: AB=BA\}.$$

Therefore we have to solve
$$\left(\begin{array}{l}a\alpha&a\beta+b\\0&1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{l}a&b\\0&1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}\alpha&\beta\\0&1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{l}\alpha&\beta\\0&1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}a&b\\0&1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{l}a\alpha&\alpha b+\beta\\0&1\end{array}\right).$$
But our $a,b$ has to be chosen, s.t. $a\beta +b=\alpha b+\beta$ or equivalently $ \beta(a-1)=b(\alpha-1)$  for any $\alpha,\beta$. Since the equation holds for any $(\alpha,\beta)$ it holds in particular for $(\alpha,\beta)=(1,1)$. But then $a-1=0$, i.e. $a=1$, and therefore $b=0$, if $p>2$. Why?

If $p=2$, we have $b\in \{0,1\}$, because if $a=1$ and $b=1$, then $\alpha=1$ ($\beta$ arbitrary) and $\alpha\in\Bbb F_2^\times$ is non-zero. If $a=1$ and $b=0$, then obiously the equation is correct for any $(\alpha,\beta)\in\Bbb F_2^\times\times \Bbb F_2^\times$.

If $p>2$, then $b=0$. Because for $(\alpha,\beta)=(2,1)$, we have with $a=1$ the equation $0=a-1=b$. It suffices to show, that with $a=1$ and $b=0$ the equation above is correct for any $\alpha,\beta$. But this is trivial.

Hence $$Z(F_{p(p-1)})=\begin{cases}\left\{\left(\begin{array}{l}1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{l}1&1\\0&1\end{array}\right)\right\}=F_{p(p-1)}&\text{ for }p=2,\\
\left\{\left(\begin{array}{l}1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)\right\}\text{ for }p>2.\end{cases}$$

<s>What do you mean by $F'_{p(p-1)}=[F_{p(p-1)}:F_{p(p-1)}]$? For me it denotes the index of $F_{p(p-1)}$ in $F_{p(p-1)}$, which is just $1$. But I think you want to denote some group. If you mean the centralizer $C_{F_{p(p-1)}}(F_{p(p-1)})$, this is obviously the same as the centre.</s>

<s>Since you only have trouble to prove, that the centre is trivial, my proof above should give you the full answer.</s>

EDIT: The OP means by $F'_{p(p-1)}=[F_{p(p-1)}:F_{p(p-1)}]$ the commutator subgroup. We set $G:=F_{p(p-1)}$. Then the commutator subgroup of $G$ is given by
$$[G,G]:=\langle\{[A,B]|A,B\in G\}\rangle\text{, where }[A,B]=ABA^{-1}B^{-1}.$$
By the same notation as above we have
$$\left(\begin{array}{l}a&b\\0&1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}\alpha&\beta\\0&1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}a^{-1}&-ba^{-1}\\0&1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}\alpha^{-1}&-\beta \alpha^{-1}\\0&1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{l}1&\beta(a-1)-b(\alpha-1)\\0&1\end{array}\right).$$
Take $\alpha=1$, $b$ arbitrary and $a=2$, then $\beta (a-1)-b(\alpha-1)=\beta\in \Bbb F_p$. So we get any element in $\Bbb F_p$. Hence 
$$[G,G]=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{l}1&x\\0&1\end{array}\right):x\in\Bbb F_p\right\}$$

For $p=2$ we also get $[G,G]=F_{p(p-1)}=Z(F_{p(p-1)})$. But for $p>2$ it can't be the trivial group, since $G:=F_{p(p-1)}$ is not commutative in general.

Comment: Do you mean the commutator subgroup $[F_{p(p-1)},F_{p(p-1)}]$?

Comment: yes i mean the comutator

Comment: and can us identify $F_{p(p-1)}/F'_{p(p-1)}$ with a  familiar group?

Comment: I think it should be iso to $\Bbb F_p^\times$. Because $\left(\begin{array}{l}a&b\\0&1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}1&x\\0&1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{l}1&ax+b\\0&1\end{array}\right)$ and for $x=-ba^{-1}$ this is $\left(\begin{array}{l}a&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)$. Therefore $\left(\begin{array}{l}a&b\\0&1\end{array}\right)F_{p(p-1)}'=\left(\begin{array}{l}a&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)F_{p(p-1)}'$ for any $a\neq0, b$ in $F_{p(p-1)}$. The iso is given by $\left(\begin{array}{l}a&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)F_{p(p-1)}\mapsto a$.

Comment: The iso also shows, that the group $F_{p(p-1)}/F_{p(p-1)}'$ is abelian. No surprise, since it is the abelianization of $F_{p(p-1)}$.